# Move UINavigationController inside a UITabBarController to first view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

When I receive a push notification, I want the navigation controller back to the first view. The tab bar is recognized, however, the navigation controller does not move back.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive){

        UITabBarController *tabb = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        tabb.selectedIndex = 0;

        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)tabb.navigationController;
        [nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I;n this line, you're saying that you want to access the UINavigationController that contains your tab controller.

```
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)tabb.navigationController;
```

However, it appears you want to access the Navigation Controller that is contained IN the tab controller.

Since it is the first controller you can access it like so:

```
UINavifationController *nav = (UINavifationController *)[tabb.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```